# javafx make button fill width

Tags: java, button, javafx

i have one button in a borderpane. I want the button to be stretched out horizontally so it fills the entire width.

how can i do that?

Comment: By either playing with pref sizes or wrapping it an an anchor pane with right and left anchors set to 0.

Comment: You need to show code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just set the `maxWidth` property of the button to `MAX_VALUE`.